# Realizar una consulta de MySQL con una variables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta `sql` en `php`, esta consulta involucra una variable `php`, pero en el momento de realizar la consulta con la variable no imprime el resultado, sin embargo, si coloco el valor de la variable en número si me imprime el resultado.

Si reemplazo el `$id` por un valor (123456) si imprime el resultado. Como se puede hacer para que la variable de `php` funcione dentro de esta consulta e imprima el resultado, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Este es mi código:

```html
$consulta = sprintf("SELECT tbl_personal.id_empleado, tbl_valor_beneficios.fecha_beneficio, Sum(tbl_valor_beneficios.valor) AS montoFinal, tbl_personal.nombre_completo, tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio FROM tbl_valor_beneficios INNER JOIN tbl_personal ON tbl_valor_beneficios.id_empleado = tbl_personal.id_empleado WHERE tbl_personal.id_empleado = $id AND tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio = 1");
$resultado = $con->query($consulta);


if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $salario =  $fila['montoFinal'];
        $nombre = $fila['nombre_completo'];

    }
}
```

Comment: La query es buena? esta probada?

Comment: Si, esta probada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle es que la función `sprintf()` requiere así mismo los tipos de datos que serán manejados en la interpolación:

Es decir en esta línea:

```
tbl_personal.id_empleado WHERE tbl_personal.id_empleado = $id
```

Se espera un entero, por lo tanto se debería ver de este modo:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

Posterior construyo la consulta

```
$sql = 'tbl_personal.id_empleado WHERE tbl_personal.id_empleado %d';
```

Ahora haciendo uso de la función en cuestión, pasamos como primer argumento la consulta SQL y posterior la variable `$id`:

```
sprintf($sql, $id);
```

O bien de otro modo:

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_personal.id_empleado, tbl_valor_beneficios.fecha_beneficio, 
        Sum(tbl_valor_beneficios.valor) AS montoFinal, 
        tbl_personal.nombre_completo, tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio FROM 
        tbl_valor_beneficios INNER JOIN tbl_personal ON 
        tbl_valor_beneficios.id_empleado = tbl_personal.id_empleado WHERE 
        tbl_personal.id_empleado = '".$id."' 
        AND tbl_valor_beneficios.id_beneficio = 1";
```

Es decir sin el uso de dicha función y solamente colocando a la variable en esta sintaxis: `'".$variableNombre."'`

> Ya te dejaron un ejemplo, así que solo lo dejo como recomendación; *deberías usar sentencias preparadas*

- [función `sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Funcionó siguiendo el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba de esta forma, no veo claro el uso de `sprintf()`

```
    $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass", "bd"); 
    $link->set_charset("utf8") or die();
    $consulta = "SELECT xxxx FROM yyyyy where id = $id";
    $resultDir = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
    if ($pos = mysqli_fetch_row($resultDir)) {
        array_push($direccionesOrigen, $pos);
    }
```

Como puedes ver uso directamente la variable PHP.
Existe otra forma de hacerlo con sentencias preparadas. Te doy un ejemplo:

```
if (!($sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
    echo "Falló la preparación: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$id = 1;
if (!$sentencia->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Falló la vinculación de parámetros: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
}

if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
    echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
}
```

Espero te sirva. ;)